# Performance difference: select top 1 order by vs. select min(val)

Tags: sql, performance, aggregate-functions

Question is simple. Which query will be faster:

```
SELECT TOP 1 value FROM table ORDER BY value
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1  MIN(value) FROM table
```

We can assume that we have two cases, Case 1. No index and Case 2. With index on value.

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to call `TOP 1` because `MIN` already returns one value.

Comment: If there will be any diffrence it will depend of dbms used so you may want to add which one you're intrested in.

Comment: The two opeartions are not equal, if there for example exists `NULL` values in the column the `TOP 1` + `order by` will return `NULL` and the `MIN` the smallest non null value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case where no index exists:

- MIN(value) should be implemented in O(N) time with a single scan;
- TOP 1 ... ORDER BY will require O(N Log N) time because of the specified sort (unless the DB engine is smart enough to read intent, which I would hate to rely on in production code).

When an index does exist:

- Both should require only O(1) time, using the index.

Comment: Thanks. Such answer I was looking for!

Comment: I saw the "Approved" come in - that is always sufficient thanks.