# More efficient method to delete data more recent than an aggregated value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running a Delete Query that works, but I cannot help but think there's a better way.

```
DECLARE @InventoryID AS INTEGER

SET @InventoryID = 987654

DELETE FROM dbo.StatusHistory
FROM dbo.InventoryItems i1
    INNER JOIN dbo.StatusHistory s1 ON s1.inventory_id = i1.inventory_id
WHERE s1.inventory_id = @InventoryID
AND s1.effective_date >
    (
    SELECT
        MIN(s2.effective_date)
    FROM dbo.InventoryItems i2
        INNER JOIN dbo.StatusHistory s2 ON s2.inventory_id = i2.inventory_id
    WHERE   (i2.inventory_id = @InventoryID)
        AND (s2.status_code = 'N')
    )
```

Comment: Instead of `SELECT min(s2.effective_date)...` try `SELECT top 1 s2.effective_date ... ORDER BY s2.effectie_date`

Comment: @Pieter interesting suggestion, [given this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15276281/61305). In what scenario do you expect `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY` to outperform `MIN`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Since the early days of Sybase SQL Server I have always understood that it is easier and more reliable for the engine to optimize in complex queries. Often it will make no difference, yet I have seen it occasionally perform much better, and occasionally worse. A key constraint of all optimizers is reasonable limits on the length of time spent optimizing, so to provide a little nudge in the right direction (when an index exists) on a problem query seems quite reasonable. As always, one should measure the results of various options for problem queries.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: In 1995 I helped a colleague deduce that a missing transitive, and thus theoretically *redundant*, join clause between the third and fifth tables caused a query's run time to increase from a few seconds to 72 hours. It is difficult to predict just how the optimizer will make decisions, so when a performance problem seems to *unnecessarily* appear, one should not make assumptions about how the optimizer will or will not be able to make certain deductions within the time constraint imposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join in the min is not required
If it is not in inventory then it will be excluded based on the first join

```
DELETE StatusHistory
  FROM InventoryItems
  JOIN StatusHistory 
    ON StatusHistory.inventory_id = InventoryItems.inventory_id
   and StatusHistory.inventory_id = @InventoryID 
   and StatusHistory.effective_date >
        ( SELECT MIN(StatusHistory.effective_date)
            FROM StatusHistory 
           WHERE StatusHistory.inventory_id = @InventoryID
             AND StatusHistory.status_code = 'N'
        )
```

If the query optimizer is getting stupid on the StatusHistory.effective_date

```
DECLARE @minDate AS DATETIME;
SET @minDate = ( SELECT MIN(StatusHistory.effective_date)
                   FROM StatusHistory 
                  WHERE StatusHistory.inventory_id = @InventoryID
                    AND StatusHistory.status_code = 'N'
               );

DELETE StatusHistory
  FROM InventoryItems
  JOIN StatusHistory 
    ON StatusHistory.inventory_id = InventoryItems.inventory_id
   and StatusHistory.inventory_id = @InventoryID 
   and StatusHistory.effective_date > @minDate;
```